# Squid Dansguardian Configuration

Tags: squid, dansguardian

Is it possible to have a squid dansguardian configuration in the below manner,

BROWSER --> SQUID --> DANSGUARDIAN --> INTERNET

We currently have a sandwich SQUID-DG-SQUID configuration. Just wanted to know this out of interest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. DG is not able to fetch pages, so needs a proxy upstream to do this. You can have browser->dg->squid->internet though. There are some advantages to the "sandwich" method, but as I am sure you know, there are also overheads in complexity.